# XSL for-each from different structure

Tags: xml, xslt, variables, foreach

I have a problem in the realization of this XSLT, what I need is to create a HTML table from the follow XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Overview>
<Header>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Language" width="10%" align="center">Lingua</Column>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Text" width="45%" align="left">Testo</Column>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Usage" width="45%" align="left">Uso</Column>
</Header>
<Rows>
  <Row row="0">
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_PKey">1</Column>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Language">it</Column>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Text">Accedi al Sistema</Column>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Usage">AppMenuLabelLogIn</Column>
  </Row>
  <Row row="1">
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_PKey">2</Column>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Language">en</Column>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Text">LogIn</Column>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Usage">AppMenuLabelLogIn</Column>
  </Row>
  <Row row="2">
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_PKey">3</Column>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Language">it</Column>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Text">Archivio</Column>
    <Column name="SysRepositoryLabel_Usage">AppMenuLabelMasterData</Column>
  </Row>
</Rows>
</Overview>
```

**This is the table that I would like to obtain:**

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" align="center" valign="center">Lingua</td>
    <td width="45%" align="left" valign="center">Testo</td>
    <td width="45%" align="left" valign="center">Uso</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" align="center" valign="center">it</td>
    <td width="45%" align="left" valign="center">Accedi al Sistema</td>
    <td width="45%" align="left" valign="center">AppMenuLabelLogIn</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" align="center" valign="center">en</td>
    <td width="45%" align="left" valign="center">LogIn</td>
    <td width="45%" align="left" valign="center">AppMenuLabelLogIn</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" align="center" valign="center">it</td>
    <td width="45%" align="left" valign="center">Archivio</td>
    <td width="45%" align="left" valign="center">AppMenuLabelMasterData</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the node Header I have to header of the table with the numbers of column of this new table and some property, as the width and the aling of the text.
In the node Rows I have the data to put in the tables, the number of row is should be more than the one of the header but only the present in the header should be exported also in the second table.

Thanks a lot Pasquale

Comment: You write "This is the table that I would like to obtain" but then you post the markup of two HTML tables, not of one. Please clarify which output you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample that assumes you want one table with a thead filled by the Header/Column elements and then a tbody populated by Rows/Row elements. And I use templates, not for-each:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="cols" select="/Overview/Header/Column"/>

  <xsl:template match="Overview">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$cols" mode="cols"/>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$cols"/>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Rows/Row"/>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Header/Column" mode="cols">
    <col width="{@width}" align="{@align}" valign="center"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Header/Column">
    <th>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </th>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Column[@name = $cols/@name]"/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row/Column">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Saxon 6.5.5, when running that stylesheet against the input you have posted, outputs

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
   <col width="10%" align="center" valign="center">
   <col width="45%" align="left" valign="center">
   <col width="45%" align="left" valign="center">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Lingua</th>
         <th>Testo</th>
         <th>Uso</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>it</td>
         <td>Accedi al Sistema</td>
         <td>AppMenuLabelLogIn</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>en</td>
         <td>LogIn</td>
         <td>AppMenuLabelLogIn</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>it</td>
         <td>Archivio</td>
         <td>AppMenuLabelMasterData</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your support, but unfortunatelly this kind of solution is not good for me, for technical reason I need to apply it using a for-each, Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @user1477028: This is not a "technical" reason at all. This is a *personal* reason that indicates your problem that you need to learn XSLT. The main purpose of SO is to learn from experts and you seem to be not wanting to learn. +1 for the good answer by Martin Honnen.

Comment: Hi, for sure I have a lot of things to learn about XSLT, take in mind that I started yesterday for first time. The problem is that using JQuery to apply your sheet it is not toke in consideration :( only this. So due to the fact that I'm not expert for the moment I think that there is a big difference between a template as your one and a simple XSLT with a for-each, I'm waiting to elapse 8h to post my solution, because I think that the problem is very easy to be fixed, but I don't understand very well the XSL pointers yet. Thanks a lot any way...

Comment: Hi, this is the part of your code that is not working in the mine one, "Column[@name = $cols/@name]", seems that the attribute $cols/@name is throwing an error, so the result of my transformation is a blank page :( I put it in a for-each like that: <xsl:for-each select="Overview/Rows/Row/Column[@name = $Cols/@name]">

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I found this night ;)

```
<xsl:variable name="Cols" select="Overview/Header/Column"/>

...

<xsl:for-each select="Column[@name = $Cols//@name]">
<td valign="center">
<xsl:variable name="CurrentCol" select="@name"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$Cols[@name = $CurrentCol]">
<xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="@width" /></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="align"><xsl:value-of select="@align" /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I don't post all the code because now I added a lot of functionality that can we lose the focus of my problem. But with this code I was able to filter the columns of the node ROW with the same columns of the node HEADER, maintaining also the properties of the header node (width, align)...